# Weird, seemingly random crashes when calling glDrawElements in iOS Simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

This bug seems to only happen in iOS Simulator, but it happens often enough that it is affecting my work.

Randomly, the app will crash in glDrawElements.

Normally, there is no ouput, but when running with GuardMalloc, I got this:

```
GuardMalloc[Sketch Nation Galaxy-92006]: Failed to VM allocate 16777216 bytes
GuardMalloc[Sketch Nation Galaxy-92006]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!
dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/DebuggerIntrospectionSupport.dylib, 0x00000002)
dyld: loaded: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/Resources/DebuggerIntrospectionSupport.dylib
```

Looking at the glDrawElements call, if the crash happens when GuardMalloc IS NOT ON, everything looks normal and it does not seem like any of the vertex or index data got corrupted. Just a weird exec_bad_access inside the glDrawElements call.

When I try to look at the data when the crash happens with GuardMalloc on, there is no data for anything, regardless of how high I climb the stack trace.

I don't know if it helps, but here is the assembly inside the glDrawElements calls:

```
OpenGLES`glDrawElements:
0x1b3f11d:  pushl  %ebp
0x1b3f11e:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1b3f120:  pushl  %ebx
0x1b3f121:  pushl  %edi
0x1b3f122:  pushl  %esi
0x1b3f123:  subl   $28, %esp
0x1b3f126:  movl   $30, (%esp)
0x1b3f12d:  calll  0x1b455c2                 ; symbol stub for: pthread_getspecific
0x1b3f132:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1b3f134:  je     0x1b3f15e                 ; glDrawElements + 65
0x1b3f136:  movl   20(%ebp), %ecx
0x1b3f139:  movl   16(%ebp), %edx
0x1b3f13c:  movl   12(%ebp), %esi
0x1b3f13f:  movl   8(%ebp), %edi
0x1b3f142:  movl   16(%eax), %ebx
0x1b3f145:  movl   %ecx, 16(%esp)
0x1b3f149:  movl   %edx, 12(%esp)
0x1b3f14d:  movl   %esi, 8(%esp)
0x1b3f151:  movl   %edi, 4(%esp)
0x1b3f155:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x1b3f158:  calll  *288(%eax)
0x1b3f15e:  addl   $28, %esp <-- CRASH HAPPENS HERE
0x1b3f161:  popl   %esi
0x1b3f162:  popl   %edi
0x1b3f163:  popl   %ebx
0x1b3f164:  popl   %ebp
0x1b3f165:  ret
```

Anyone have any idea?

This crash happens randomly on any of my glDrawElement calls. My most common call is to a "triangle-strip square" used to render sprites:

```
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, byteStride, m_pVertexData );
glTexCoordPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, byteStride, m_pVertexData+6 );

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, m_numVertices, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pIndices);
```

m_pVertexData is created from m_pVertices, which is a struct.

```
m_numVertices = 4;
m_stride = sizeof( GEMeshVertex ) / sizeof( GLFloat );

int vertexCounter = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].x = -0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].y = 0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].z = 0;   
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nx = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].ny = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nz = 1;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tu = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tv = 1;

vertexCounter++;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].x = -0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].y = -0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].z = 0;   
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nx = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].ny = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nz = 1;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tu = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tv = 0;

vertexCounter++;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].x = 0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].y = 0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].z = 0;   
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nx = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].ny = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nz = 1;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tu = 1;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tv = 1;

vertexCounter++;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].x = 0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].y = -0.5;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].z = 0;   
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nx = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].ny = 0;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].nz = 1;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tu = 1;
m_pVertices[vertexCounter].tv = 0;

m_pIndices = new GLubyte[m_numVertices];
m_pIndices[0] = 0;
m_pIndices[1] = 1;
m_pIndices[2] = 2;
m_pIndices[3] = 3;

for( i = 0; i < m_numVertices; i++ )
{
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+0] = m_pVertices[i].x;
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+1] = m_pVertices[i].y;
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+2] = m_pVertices[i].z;
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+3] = m_pVertices[i].nx;
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+4] = m_pVertices[i].ny;
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+5] = m_pVertices[i].nz;
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+6] = m_pVertices[i].tu;
    m_pVertexData[(i*stride)+7] = m_pVertices[i].tv;
}
```

Being a 2d app, I am not using the normals.

Here is the struct that holds the m_pVertices data:

```
class GEMeshVertex {
public:
    float x, y, z;   // The untransformed position for the vertex.
    float nx,ny,nz;
    float tu, tv;    // The texture coordinates
} PACK_STRUCT;
```

PACK_STRUCT is a macro to byte align the struct:

```
#   define PACK_STRUCT  __attribute__((packed))
```

Comment: You're probably using the wrong array size somewhere and drawElements is trying to access an address outside of it's buffer. Can you put up the code leading up to drawElements? Anything related to buffers, pointers, etc would be relevant.

Comment: Added. Hope that helps. As you can see my vertex/indices are very simple. The same calls runs perfectly fine until the crash. If GUARD_MALLOC is not on, I can see that m_pVertexData and m_pIndices have not changed.

Comment: Is `stride` the same as `m_stride`? What size is that giving you?

Comment: When I coped and pasted the code I missed the stride = m_stride line. Stride is 8. I'll add the struct for m_pVertices to the question.

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this? having something similar...

Comment: Never did. Still happens sometimes in simulator, never on device.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem and was unable to solve it for a long time. Only recently I discovered that it's probably not even a bug in my code. It seems that the exception is caught and handled by the simulator just fine. If I let the debugger resume execution, the application continues as if nothing happend.

The fact that my app never crashes while idling in the simulator without an attached debugger also speaks for this theory. Furthermore my app never has this problem while running on an actual device.

God knows what the OpenGL ES emulator does behind the scenes. It seems to expect this specific exception as it is prepared to recover from it.

It's a pity though that one cannot instruct Xcode to ignore specific exceptions or exceptions in specific modules. But this is rather an annoyance than a major problem.

For now I assume that everything is fine until I discover evidence that contradicts my findings.